# Inconsolata font with powerline support and italics

Tags: macos, vim, fonts, macvim

Is there an Inconsolata font package with italics and support for powerline? I have only been able to find:

- [powerline-fonts](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fonts) - has powerline support but no italics
- [Inconsolata-LGC](https://github.com/MihailJP/Inconsolata-LGC) - has italics but not powerline support

Otherwise is there an easy way of merging the two so the powerline characters work and I can see code comments in italic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If google says "no", the answer must be "no", right?

But… what about creating it yourself with lokaltog's [powerline-fontpatcher](https://github.com/Lokaltog/powerline-fontpatcher)? After all, that's what everybody did before he made that font pack available.